# Usage of Ask pattern causing the creation of default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher threads for each request

Tags: scala, akka

Information: You might want to skip directly to Edit 4 after the introduction.

Recently I wrote a simple scala server app. The app mostly wrote incoming data to the database or retrieved it. This is my first scala-akka application.
When I deployed the app to my server it failed after about a day. I realized from the simple statistics provided by digitalocean that the CPU usage was rising in a linear fashion if I s̶e̶n̶d̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶t̶o̶  request data from the server. If I didn't s̶e̶n̶d̶  request anything from the server the CPU usage was about constant but wasn't falling from it's previous state.
I connected the app to visualvm and saw that the number of threads is either constant if I don't do anything with the app (I), or grows if I send stuff to the server (II) in a saw-like fashion.
[image]
There is an obvious coloration here between the number of threads and CPU usage which makes sens.
When I checked the threads tab I saw that most threads are `default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher` threads
[image]
They also don't seem to be doing much.

**What could cause this sort of problem? How do I solve it?**
Ad. Edit4: I think I found the source of the problem, but I still don't understand why it happens, and how I should solve it.

PS: I must admit that the screenshots are not from the application which failed. I don't have any from the original failure. However the only difference between this program and the one that failed is that in `application.conf` I added:

```
actor {
    default-dispatcher {
      fork-join-executor {
        # Settings this to 1 instead of 3 seems to improve performance.
        parallelism-factor = 2.0

        parallelism-max = 24

        task-peeking-mode = FIFO
      }
    }
  }
```

This seems to have slowed the speed by which the number of threads rises, but didn't solve the problem.

Edit: Fragment of WriterActor usage ([RestApi](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/65fd751fdb77533d793ebf0b09f94aa7))

```
trait RestApi extends CassandraCluster {
  import models._
  import cassandraDB.{WriterActor, ReaderActor}
  implicit def system: ActorSystem
  implicit def materializer: ActorMaterializer
  implicit def ec: ExecutionContext

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(20 seconds)

  val cassandraWriterWorker = system.actorOf(Props(new WriterActor(cluster)), "cassandra-writer-actor")
  val cassandraReaderWorker = system.actorOf(Props(new ReaderActor(cluster)), "cassandra-reader-actor")
  ...
  def cassandraReaderCall(message: Any): ToResponseMarshallable = message match {
    //...
    case message: GetActiveContactsByPhoneNumber => (cassandraReaderWorker ? message)(2 seconds).mapTo[Vector[String]].map(result => Json.obj("active_contacts" -> result))
    case _ => StatusCodes.BadRequest
  }

  def confirmedWriterCall(message: Any) = {
    (cassandraWriterWorker ? message).mapTo[Boolean].map(result => result)
  }

  val apiKeyStringV1 = "test123"

  val route =
    ...
        path("contacts") {
          parameter('apikey ! apiKeyStringV1) {
            post {
              entity(as[Contacts]){ contact: Contacts =>
                cassandraWriterWorker ! contact
                complete(StatusCodes.OK)
              }
            } ~
            get {
              parameter('phonenumber) { phoneNumber: String =>
                complete(cassandraReaderCall(GetActiveContactsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)))
              }
            }
          }
        } ~
        } ~
        path("log"/ "gps") {
          parameter('apikey ! apiKeyStringV1) {
            (post & entity(as[GpsLog])) { gpsLog =>
              cassandraWriterWorker ! gpsLog
              complete(StatusCodes.OK)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Writer Worker relevant code.
I didn't post all the methods since they are all basically the same. But [here](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/7a7d86be9422e1a1cbada4ebc97606ca) you can find the whole file

```
import java.util.UUID

import akka.actor.Actor
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
import models._

class WriterActor(cluster: Cluster) extends Actor{
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

  val session = cluster.connect(Keyspaces.akkaCassandra)

  // ... other inserts
  val insertGpsLog = session.prepare("INSERT INTO gps_logs(id, phone_number, lat, long, time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);")

  // ...
  def insertGpsLog(phoneNumber: String, locWithTime: LocationWithTime): Unit =
    session.executeAsync(insertGpsLog.bind(UUID.randomUUID().toString, phoneNumber, new java.lang.Double(locWithTime.location.lat),
      new java.lang.Double(locWithTime.location.long), new java.lang.Long(locWithTime.time)))

  def receive: Receive = {
    // ...
    case gpsLog: GpsLog => gpsLog.locationWithTimeLog.foreach(locWithTime => insertGpsLog(gpsLog.phoneNumber, locWithTime))
  }
}
```

Edit 3. Miss diagnosis of excessive thread use.

I'm afraid I miss diagnosed the origin of the problem.Later on, I have added a request for data after the write and forgot about it. When I removed it the number of threads stopped growing. So this is the most likely place where the mistake was made. I updated the trait where the [ReaderActor](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/736684b61c1fe4fa6a93fcf6b01fec81) is used and also added the relevant code of the ReaderActor below.

```
object ReaderActor {
  // ...
  case class GetActiveContactsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String)
}

class ReaderActor(cluster: Cluster) extends Actor {
  import models._
  import ReaderActor._
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  import cassandra.resultset._
  import context.dispatcher

  val session = cluster.connect(Keyspaces.akkaCassandra)

  def buildActiveContactByPhoneNumberResponse(r: Row): String = {
    val phoneNumber = r.getString(ContactsKeys.phoneNumber)
    return phoneNumber
  }

  def buildSubSelectContactsList(r: Row): java.util.List[String] = {
    val phoneNumber = r.getSet(ContactsKeys.contacts, classOf[String])
    return phoneNumber.toList
  }

  def receive: Receive = {
    //...
    case GetActiveContactsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) =>
      val subQuery = QueryBuilder.select(ContactsKeys.contacts).
        from(Keyspaces.akkaCassandra, ColumnFamilies.contact).
        where(QueryBuilder.eq(ContactsKeys.phoneNumber, phoneNumber))
      def queryActiveUsers(phoneNumbers: java.util.List[String]) = QueryBuilder.select(ContactsKeys.phoneNumber).
        from(Keyspaces.akkaCassandra, ColumnFamilies.contact).
        where(QueryBuilder.in(ContactsKeys.phoneNumber, phoneNumbers))
      session.execute(subQuery) map((row: Row) => session.executeAsync(queryActiveUsers(buildSubSelectContactsList(row))) map(_.all().map(buildActiveContactByPhoneNumberResponse).toVector) pipeTo sender)
    //...
  }
}
```

Edit 4
I run the code locally, controlling all the request. When there are no requests the number of running threads alternates around a certain number, but doesn't have a tendency to go up or down.
I made a variety of requests to see what will change.
The Image posted below shows several states.

- I - no requests yet. number of threads 44-45
- II - after a request to the ReaderActor. number of threads 46-47
- III - after a request to the ReaderActor. number of threads 48-49
- IV - after a request to the ReaderActor. number of threads 50-51
- V - after a request to the WrtierActor. number of threads 51-52 (but no problem, notice a daemon thread was started)
- VI - after a request to the WriterActor. number of threads 51-52 (constant)
- VII - after a request to the ReaderActor (but a different resource then the first three). number of threads 53-54

[image: local_test_num_of_threads]

So what happens is every time we read from the database (regardless how many executeAsync calls are used) 2 extra threads are created. The only difference between the read and the write calls is that one uses the ask pattern and the other doesn't. I checked it by changing the route from:

```
            get {
                  parameter('phonenumber) { phoneNumber: String =>
                    complete(cassandraReaderCall(GetActiveContactsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)))
                  }
                }
```

to

```
        get {
              parameter('phonenumber) { phoneNumber: String =>
                cassandraReaderWorker ! GetActiveContactsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                complete(StatusCodes.OK)
              }
            }
```

obviously not getting any results now, but also not spawning those threads.
So the answer seems to lie in the ask pattern.

**I hope somebody can provide an answer as to why this happens and how to solve it?**

Comment: Hum, are you sure that the second picture is showing only live threads? Anyway, if your application is failing after a day or so, you probably have a resource leak. According to [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#Listing_of_the_Reference_Configuration), your configuration looks fine (at least the section you shared here). You should probably take a memory/thread dump from your process and analyze it (use visualvm for both).

Comment: @marcospereira You are probably right about the threads. At the top of the screen it says live threads, but there is also a drop down list where I can sub select all threads, live threds, or finished threads. So the list probably showed all threads. Could you point me in a direction how I should interpret the [thread dump](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/6a7398f82880fa44670202ae2ef20948).

Comment: Is it possible that you create new actors with every request and don't kill them after they are finished?

Comment: @rincewind I think not. I just added a piece of code. The trait is the only place i use this actor. and I only create it once. Was there anything in the thread dump which made you think I did?

Comment: Share the code for WriteWork.

Comment: @marcospereira I added the requested code.

Comment: @marcospereira I'm sorry I think I misled you in my original question. The problem likely originates in a different place. Could you please have another look at the updated question.

Comment: @Lukasz Maybe you should take a look here: 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html

Akka ask pattern creates Futures, which make use of threads to execute asynchronous.

Comment: I'm also seeing this in our application, using a similar ask pattern to access (Slick/Postgre) database. The app reached 13000+ threads until we killed it. Upon startup it only allocates 60 threads...

Comment: @ochrons I changed a lot of code, to get it to work, and frankly I was stumbling in the dark until I solved it. I think what finally removed the problem, for reasons I don't understand, was moving the mapping to Json into the reader actor.

Comment: In my case it turned out to be extra ActorSystems created accidentally in one part of the code base.